# HTML Page Refresh and Session

Tags: php, html, session, url, refresh

I am in a confusion with our application . I am passing username and password in the URL

like

http://mysite.com/login?userid=abc&password=test

this is taking me to the login page ( asks for credentials) and again if I hit the browser with simply using keyboard enter key on the same URL or Contrl+F5 it works fine ( It take me to the welcome page of the user) . So hitting the same URL working fine .

Not sure why the second time it is working fine . But with that what I did was in a simple HTML file I wrote the below two lines ( I just want to automate those two hits )

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://mysite.com/login?userid=abc&password=test">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://mysite.com/login?userid=abc&password=test">
```

so this loads the page twice and my assumption was it should take to the user welcome page . since I am loading it twice . But again takes me the login page . Again simple enter and it works fine .

Please advise me how to automate this two step process in a simple HTML or in PHP or in any other programing language  .

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: **Never ever** have a password in the GET string. It will show up in the browser cache, and the server logs, and can be eavesdropped on. You need to re-think this approach, and either way show some more detail and PHP code

Comment: Never ever, ever, ever, pass passwords through the URL.  Edit: Bah, too slow.

Comment: you should add some code of what you have tried so far

Comment: Go to your login page then Ctrl + A followed by Del... Then redesign

Comment: I am sorry the application is not under my control . what they asked me to do is implementing some fake page or URLS that will allow the user to login to the application automatically . And also the application is accepting GET parameters . But only problem here is hitting the fake URL that I build twice is working fine and one time it is not working . How to automate the hitting the twice the same URL in HTML ? for that I did refresh . But this didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login.html

```
<form action="auth.php" method="POST">
   <input name="username" value="" />
   <input name="password" value="" />

   <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

auth.php

```
if($_POST['username] == 'abc' && $_POST['password'] == 'test')
{
   //redirect to welcome page
}
```

of course you should check username and password a little bit more professional than this but i think is enough to understand.

if you just need to request an url twice maybe what you're looking for is curl, [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: I am sorry the application is not under my control . what they asked me to do is implementing some fake page or URLS that will allow the user to login to the application automatically . And also the application is accepting GET parameters . But only problem here is hitting the fake URL that I build twice is working fine and one time it is not working . How to automate the hitting the twice the same URL in HTML ? for that I did refresh . But this didn't work .

Comment: i think the right way to follow is understand why you need to send twice the login data. To send the user/password via get just turn method to get on the html code above.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like the code that handles auto login is only firing off on post-back. I would investigate what the conditions of this code firing off are.